# How to get a specific value from variable type integer()?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, integer

I need to check the value of the player's hand in a game of blackjack. To do this, I have found the length of the user's hand and am trying to add the values of each card as it goes along. However, this code returns an error whenever it's called to:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the
> array.'

How would I go about resolving this or just finding a way to check the player's hand value?

```vb
Public Shared Function check(p As Player) As Integer
    Dim value As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To p.length - 1
        value += p.getHand(i).getValue(i)
    Next
    Return value
End Function
```

`getHand()` returns a list of "Cards"

`getValue()` returns the value of the cards (in blackjack) as data type integer() (because of the value of the ace in Blackjack)
Update: This is the code for the `Player` class

```
Public Class Player

Private name As String
Private hand As New List(Of Card)
Private _hasStuck As Boolean

Public Sub New(aName As String)
    Me.name = aName
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property getName() As String
    Get
        Return Me.name
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property getHand() As List(Of Card)
    Get
        Return Me.hand
    End Get
End Property

Public Property hasStuck() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _hasStuck
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _hasStuck = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function getHandAsString() As String
    Return "[" & String.Join(", ", Me.getHand.ConvertAll(Function(c) c.ToString)) & "]"
End Function

Public Function length() As Integer
    Return hand.Count
End Function
```

End Class

Update #2:  This is the code for the class `Card`

```
Public Class Card

Private suit As String
Private faceValue As String
Private value() As Integer
Private image As Bitmap

Public Sub New(aSuit As String, aValue As String, actualValue() As Integer, cardImage As Bitmap)
    Me.suit = aSuit
    Me.faceValue = aValue
    Me.value = actualValue
    Me.image = cardImage
End Sub

Private ReadOnly Property getSuit() As String
    Get
        Return Me.suit
    End Get
End Property

Private ReadOnly Property getFaceValue() As String
    Get
        Return Me.faceValue
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property getValue() As Integer()
    Get
        Return Me.value
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property getImage() As Bitmap
    Get
        Return Me.image
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return getFaceValue & " of " & getSuit
End Function
```

This is the function used to create a deck and assign each card a value:

```
    Public Sub createDeck()
    Me.theDeck = New List(Of Card)
    Dim JQK() As String = {"Jack", "Queen", "King"}

    For x As Integer = 1 To 13
        Dim face As String = If(x = 1, "Ace", If(x < 11, x.ToString, JQK(x - 11)))
        Dim values() As Integer = If(x = 1, New Integer() {1, 11}, If(x < 11, New Integer() {x}, New Integer() {10}))
        Me.getDeck.Add(New Card("Hearts", face, values, New Bitmap("deck\card" & (x + 25).ToString & ".png")))
        Me.getDeck.Add(New Card("Diamonds", face, values, New Bitmap("deck\card" & (x + 38).ToString & ".png")))
        Me.getDeck.Add(New Card("Clubs", face, values, New Bitmap("deck\card" & (x - 1).ToString & ".png")))
        Me.getDeck.Add(New Card("Spades", face, values, New Bitmap("deck\card" & (x + 12).ToString & ".png")))
    Next

    Me.shuffleDeck()
End Sub
```

Comment: Without knowing the `Player` class it is rather hard to guess possible traps. Maybe you 'd like to share the `Player`.

Comment: Are you sure you can use the same indexer for both `getHand()` and `getValue()`? It *sounds* weird. Probably you want to iterate over the collection of cards that represent the current Hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions in this response because I do not know what your `Player` class, `getHand` method, or `getValue` method look like.

What you should probably do is get the list of cards, iterate over the cards, and get the value of the currently iterated card:

```vb
Public Shared Function check(p As Player) As Integer
    Dim value As Integer = 0

    For Each item In p.getHand()
        value += item.getValue()
    Next

    Return value
End Function
```

Or simplified:

```vb
Public Shared Function check(p As Player) As Integer
    Return p.getHand().Sum(Function(item) item.getValue())
End Function
```

Comment: It returns either: "Operator '+' is not defined for types 'Integer' and 'Integer()'. or Error BC30518

Comment: @ItwasmeDIO - could you post the code for the `getValue` method?

Comment: Public ReadOnly Property getValue() As Integer()
        Get
            Return Me.value
        End Get
    End Property

Comment: @ItwasmeDIO ... and what is `Me.value`?

Comment: 'Me.value' is an attribute of the class 'Card', it's stored as integer()

Comment: @ItwasmeDIO how are you actually assigning a numeric value to a card? e.g. K = 10, A = 1 or 11?

Comment: I've put the code in the original post as part of edit #2